# Eclipse Error: Could not find or load main class opencv

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I keep getting these error every time I try to run the jar file I follow most of the questions that have been asked here haven't worked :(

and every time I export the jar file I got these warning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGUCX.png)

and this is my MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: gui_rec.Main
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to specify in your `MANIFEST.MF` classes to include in `the Class-Path` header field in the manifest file of an applet or application. The Class-Path header takes the following form:

```
   Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name
```

For more info go to [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)